# Nginx / libxml error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, libxml2

I installed nginx server on my Ubuntu using repos...

When I am starting the server I am getting this error:

```
    starting nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)``
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

This is what I see using locate

locate libxml2.so.2

```
    /home/john/Downloads/libxml2-2.7.8/.libs/libxml2.so.2
    /home/john/Downloads/libxml2-2.7.8/.libs/libxml2.so.2.7.8
    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1
    /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2
    /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
```

What is the issue and how to fix it ?

Comment: How did you install nginx?

Comment: using apt-get install

Answer (score 0):

You have a manually compiled libxml in `/usr/local`. Perhaps Direct Admin? Either get rid of it or don't use the ubuntu package and compile nginx from source.